# JSON string in MS SQL Server is too large to select without CAST ing to XML

Tags: json, sql-server, nvarchar, open-json

We have event data in a log table that is a JSON string of NVARCHAR(MAX) datatype. Some of the strings are too large to SELECT out of the table. But, if we CAST it, we can see the entire value.

```
SELECT CAST('<![CDATA[' + @JsonResult + ']]>' AS XML);
```

But now, the datatype is XML even though the value looks like JSON and ***is a valid JSON array*** if I copy/paste into a linter.

How can I work on this information using MS SQL JSON features such as

```
JSON_VALUE(myJson, '$.myValue')
```

or

```
OPENJSON(myJson, '$.myThings')
```

Comment: How did you try to select the value and what happened? You don't just select a 2GB-sized string. Did you get an error or exception? In what language? Casting to XML isn't the solution.

Comment: `we can see the entire value` see it where? Are you sure the problem isn't that the *application* you're using truncates text that's too large to display? SSMS for example displays only the first 65K characters

Comment: just work with it, the code itself handle things just fine in general. SSMS might truncate your selects but that doesn't mean the actual values are truncated

Comment: "Some of the strings are too large to SELECT out of the table." why, it should work fine up to 2GB? And why do you think using CDATA is the answer?

Comment: @Charlieface probably cause xml data has 2mb as default length in ssms